# Set focus on component after modal close

Tags: ember.js

I would like to know what is recommended way to focus on component from outside the component. I am trying to focus on a input field when the person closes the modal window.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would use an action in the modal that triggers when the close button is clicked, and you would send the action up to the component with the input with `sendAction`. In the component with the input, you could then use Ember.$ or any other method to tell the browser to focus on an element.

The situation is more complex if the modal is not inside the component that contains the input. In that case you might need to use a service or event. But it's much easier to use the first method.

Comment: I have already have action triggered when the modal is closed, but I was was wondering if there was better way to focus on element instead of just relying JQuery.

Comment: `document.getElementById("myTextField").focus();` is fine too. We use jQuery for stuff like this, though.